# Javascript return from function after JQuery animation complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to hide the block and after this show another one using two different functions.

But here's problem: second function doesn't wait for completion of first. But i want to let it execute synchronous.

Here's code:

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<br>
<div id="b"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

#b {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    background: orange;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function hideA() 
{
    $("#a").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        console.log("hideA is done");
    });
};

function showB()
{
    $("#b").css('display', 'inline-block');
    $("#b").animate({opacity: 1}, 700);
    console.log("ShowB is done");
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        hideA();
        showB();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yamaha/2pmp3hzf
Open your browser console there and click green div. You will see "ShowB is done" and after "hideA is done", but it should be vice versa!

How to fix this?

Comment: You clearly know that the animating is asynchronous, and that `animate()` has a callback function to handle this, yet in one of the animations you're not using a callback, and you're still expecting the console log to wait for the animation? Why!

Comment: @adeneo, i thought javascript function wait till whole code inside this will done; so there is no way force this?

Comment: It generally does, but not when it's asynchronous. `animate` returns a promise, I would use that.

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2pmp3hzf/2/**

Comment: @adeneo, wow exactly this! Thank you :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has built in functions for fading an element, and they hide and show automagically, so they do exactly the same as your animations.

Also, all animating methods in jQuery can be made to return a promise, that way you can handle much of the logic in the calling context, which in my opinion makes it easier to keep track, something like this

```
function hideA() {
    return $("#a").fadeOut(500).promise();
};

function showB() {
    return $("#b").fadeIn(700).promise();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#a").click(function () {

        hideA().done(function() { // first is done
            console.log("hideA is done");

            showB().done(function() {  // second is done
                console.log("ShowB is done");
            });
        });

    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2pmp3hzf/2/)

Answer (score 2):

So you just need to pass your second function handler as param to first function:

```
function hideA(callback) 
{
    $("#a").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        console.log("hideA is done");
        callback();
    });
};
//...
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        hideA(showB);
    });
});
```